# How we can take mean from several excel files place wise using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, csv

[Link to Sample Data Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ziZdr2K_VWgihuTKkvoEPXhiZNH81F9i?usp=share_link)

I have 13 excel files in a folder, each of the excel file have 100 columns and uncertain rows (i.e.- may be from 20 to 40 rows depending upon the resultant data).

I want a single excel file which will have the average value from all files row-wise and column-wise.

For more details, I would like to take the mean of A11 rows from all 13 excel files and similarly for each and every row.

I tried taking mean through pandas mean method but it gives averaged mean of all values. I could not figure out how to take the average for each and every row.

Comment: Can you add sample data for one file and expected output?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ziZdr2K_VWgihuTKkvoEPXhiZNH81F9i?usp=share_link

Comment: The above link is the sample data and expected output is also there

Comment: Please do not link to data, include example data in your question. [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import glob

#create list of files
files = glob.glob('Sample_Data/*.csv')
#create list of DataFrames, join to one big DataFrame
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in files], axis=1)
print (df)

#get means per same columns names
df1 = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()
print (df1)
```

Comment: The above answer does not give the correct answer for my data. Can you please check once with my given sample data with my Result file in the linked folder?

Comment: @HarshSingh - hmmm, how are count ouput file? E.g first value from first column?

Comment: @HarshSingh - What means `I would like to take the mean of A11 rows` ? There are no A11 values, I try filter first 9,10,11 columns and still ouput different.

Comment: Output result should print the average of all first row value from first column at same place.

Comment: @HarshSingh - Understand, answer was edited.

Comment: Thank you so much..! Now I got the desired output.